# How can I use Cycles to render in Google Cloud?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, network

I want to try the free trial on Google Cloud.

Its possible render through google cloud using blender cycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, you will need to create a renderfarm on that cloud service, and then simply use it.

For similar services, from another provider, there is BRENDA https://github.com/jamesyonan/brenda, thus it could be possible to build one using another coud service, probably.

There was a talk at BC2013 about BRENDA: http://www.blender.org/conference/2013/presentations/25, if this can help you to better understand how this can work.

Answer (score 3):

I am not good in programming so I did it this way...

I install VM whit 8 cores Hight cpu 2,6ghz xeon whit 8gb ram... 50 gb HDD and Windows server 2012 .... Its exatly 274 dollars... On your free trial you have free 300 dollars... What is amazing...

After install VM , you can log in using Remote Desktom Connection... Open Internet Explorer, download Blender Zip file from blender.org...

And you can render under blender GUI..

Noob way whit using mouse and 0 commands...

:)

Comment: This does seem quite simple. I used linux computer engine. Followed theirinstructions to set up ssh and sftp. Then wget blender from the download address, had to apt-get install app for extracting tar.bz2 and modules for about three required .so files that blender complained about. Then it just ran renders (command line) - quite a bit faster than this old laptop and it was only 4 core. The charge seems to be just while the instance is switched on so 32 core would be on proportionately less time and the cost would be the same! (It seems to be about $0.05 per hour per core - amazing)